# Python: Unique list (based on part of file path)

Tags: python, list

Sorry; I know there are a thousand 'make unique list' threads. I've tried to solve this on my own, or to hack another "make unique list" solution, but I've been unsuccessful with my not amazing python skills.

I have a list of video file names (these are shots in a movie).  For any given shot I want to remove duplicates, based on part of the path (circled in red in the image below); only the one with the highest **tk_**value  should end up in the final list.

*e.g  In the image below, for shot **de05_001** only **tk_3** should end up in the list.*

[image]

Input (with duplicates):

```
raw_list = ['D:\\de05\\de05_001\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_001.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_001\\postvis\\tk_3\\blasts\\tb205_de05_001.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_002\\postvis\\tk_1\\blasts\\tb205_de05_002.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_017\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_017.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_3\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_4\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_1\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov', ]
```

Output (duplicates removed, only highest tk_ numbers remain):

```
outputList = ['D:\\de05\\de05_001\\postvis\\tk_3\\blasts\\tb205_de05_001.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_002\\postvis\\tk_1\\blasts\\tb205_de05_002.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_017\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_017.POSTVIS.mov', 
'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_4\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov', ]
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Give us a sample input and output (in plain text, not screenshots, so we can copy)

Comment: There is also a `tk_4`, shouldn't that be the one to end up in the list?

Comment: @BubbleHacker I realise it's hard to see, but that tk_4 is a different shot -de05_019  (the green circled part is different.).  So for that shot, it would indeed be in the final list since all the other de05_019 have a lower tk_ number.

Comment: Updated my answer based on the latest dataset that wasn't working. Now they both work.

Comment: You want a `set()`. Yes it's that simple :)

Comment: Set ensures uniqueness *only*, you'd still have to track the highest take. The comparison could be simplified if you just sorted the original list though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a dictionary and keep reassigning the keys, so you only end up with the last value in the directory:

```
import os

raw_list1 = [
    'D:\\\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_3\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_4\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_1\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\\\tw05\\tw05_036\\postvis\\tk_9\\blasts\\tb205_tw05_036.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\\\tw05\\tw05_036\\postvis\\tk_13\\blasts\\tb205_tw05_036.POSTVIS.mov'
]
raw_list2 = [
    'D:\\de05\\de05_001\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_001.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\de05\\de05_001\\postvis\\tk_3\\blasts\\tb205_de05_001.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\de05\\de05_002\\postvis\\tk_1\\blasts\\tb205_de05_002.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\de05\\de05_017\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_017.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_3\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_4\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
    'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_1\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov',
]

def path_split(p, folders=None):
    folders = folders or []
    head, tail = os.path.split(p)
    if not tail:
        return folders
    return path_split(head, [tail] + folders)

for raw_list in (raw_list1, raw_list2):
    results = {}

    for p in raw_list:
        # Split your path accordingly
        # For something simple you could have just done s.split('\\'), but since we're working with paths, we might as well use os.path.split
        shot1, shot2, folder1, take, folder2, file_name = path_split(p)
        # If something like 'de05_019' defines your shot, make that the key
        key = shot2
        # Extract the take number into an integer
        new_take_num = int(take.split('_')[-1])
        # Try finding the take you already stored (default to Nones)
        existing_take_num, existing_path = results.get(key, (None, None))
        # See if the new take is bigger than the existing one, based on the take number.
        # Lambda is there for comparison, meaning I'm only comparing the take numbers, not the paths. I'll link the docs to max in the comments.
        value = max((existing_take_num, existing_path), (new_take_num, p), key=lambda take_num_and_path: take_num_and_path[0])
        # Assign the value (which is either the existing take, or the new take)
        results[key] = value

    for res in sorted(results.values()):
        print res
    print '*' * 80
```

This outputs (you could also just `print res[1]` to only print the path):

```
(4, 'D:\\\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_4\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov')
(13, 'D:\\\\tw05\\tw05_036\\postvis\\tk_13\\blasts\\tb205_tw05_036.POSTVIS.mov')
********************************************************************************
(1, 'D:\\de05\\de05_002\\postvis\\tk_1\\blasts\\tb205_de05_002.POSTVIS.mov')
(2, 'D:\\de05\\de05_017\\postvis\\tk_2\\blasts\\tb205_de05_017.POSTVIS.mov')
(3, 'D:\\de05\\de05_001\\postvis\\tk_3\\blasts\\tb205_de05_001.POSTVIS.mov')
(4, 'D:\\de05\\de05_019\\postvis\\tk_4\\blasts\\tb205_de05_019.POSTVIS.mov')
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks @Bahrom.  I can't tell what part of the code sorts by the take number.  Can you explain that to me? I'm trying it with a different data set and it's not yielding the shot with the highest take number.

Comment: Can  you post the data set you're trying with?

Comment: @samusugiru ill update tomorrow morning with more details/explanation, getting late here today, sorry!

Comment: Updated original post. In the code there are only two unique shots, in the second, tk_13 is not ending up in the final list.

Comment: Thank you @Bahrom, that works like a dream.  I understand it all except the lambda bit.  Could you help me understand? (I'm also googling everything I can find on lambda)

Comment: That lambda is the key function used to compare two entries in [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)